# node.js user log in. no database only javascript array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, authentication

first of all, thank you for trying to help me.
I am just starting out with node and js and i have quite some things to learn.
I am simply just doing a college task where i have to make a login functionality, without actually registering the user but instead writing default users in an js array without databases only for testing purposes.

I created the users array:

```
 const userDB = [

{ 

   email: "chris@gmail.com",
    password: "chris"

},

{

    email: "jack@gmail.com",
    password: "jack"
}
  ];
   module.exports = { userDB };
```

And here is my js function:

```
   app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
try{

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        let foundUser = users.find((data) => req.body.email === data.email);
        if (foundUser) {

        let submittedPass = req.body.password; 
        let storedPass = foundUser.password; 

        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(submittedPass, storedPass);
        if (passwordMatch) {
            let usrname = foundUser.username;
            res.send(`<div align ='center'><h2>login successful</h2></div><br><br><br><div align ='center'><h3>Hello ${usrname}</h3></div><br><br><div align='center'><a href='/login.html'>logout</a></div>`);
        } else {
        res.send("<div align ='center'><h2>Invalid email or password</h2></div><br><br><div align ='center'><a href='/login.html'>login again</a></div>");
        }
    }

        else {

        let fakePass = `$2b$$10$ifgfgfgfgfgfgfggfgfgfggggfgfgfga`;
        await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, fakePass);

        res.send("<div align ='center'><h2>Invalid email or password</h2></div><br><br><div 
           align='center'><a href='/login.html'>login again<a><div>");
    }
}
}
```

But whenever i try to log in the default user from the array it just says invalid email/password.
Any help would be gladly appreciated!!

Comment: [The difference between Java and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java).

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that this line will return `undefined`:

```
let usrname = foundUser.username
```

since your user model does not have a property called username.

Furthermore you should narrow down the error: do you get your "invalid" response from the nested if/else or from the main? Are you sure that you have a `foundUser`? Try to `console.log()` your expected values.

Comment: I edited it but still i can't log in. Maybe i am checking wrong here? What is the proper way to check from a user array on the back end when i put email and password on the front end?

Comment: start to debug from top to bottom: `console.log(users)` does that work? `console.log(foundUser)` does that work, and so on. And If you have a `try` - you also want to have a `catch`